# Broken code generation for out function parameters

Tags: redhawksdr

I made my own interface, simplistic version looks like this:

```
#ifndef _FOO_IDL_
#define _FOO_IDL_

module FOO {
    typedef unsigned long Bar;

    interface FOOInterface {
        void getBar(out FOO::Bar b);
    };
};

#endif
```

After that I made "REDHAWK IDL Project", used that IDL, compiled, installed.

Then I made Redhawk component, added output port and used that interface on it, did code generation. During compilation I got error:

```
port_impl.h:26:29: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token
     void getBar(FOO::Bar&& b);
```

It looks like code generator adds excessive ampersand. What could I do about it?

Thank you.

Comment: I have seen the same issue with many but not all interfaces.  I have not determined exactly types this occurs for.  I just hand edit them out every time I regenerate.

Comment: Yes, that is not legal CORBA, seems a bug in the IDL compiler that you are using